# General Cucumber Clarification

Tags: cucumber

I am interested in Cucumber, but am confused a bit. From the website:
1) Define stories in plain text.
2) Write a step definition in Ruby
3) Run and watch it fail
4) Write code to make the step pass
etc...

Does that mean you can only use Cucumber for projects which are written in Ruby? What about using it for a whole web app written in various languages and/or various platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like I'm giving the same answer today three times.

My current team successfully used Cucumber to test two different web apps running on a Java EE platform.  Several teams in my organization are using it to test similar Java EE apps.  One team  used Cucumber to test a batch application, and some others are looking at testing legacy COBOL and database apps with it.

Some use Cucumber natively with Ruby, others are using [Cuke4Duke](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cuke4duke). Look for examples using Cucumber with [Watir](https://github.com/cheezy/uitesting_blog), [Celerity](https://github.com/alisterscott/WatirMelonCucumber), or [watir-webdriver](http://twofourone.blogspot.com/2011/04/cucumber-with-celerity-and-watir.html) for testing Web Apps.

Answer (score 1):

You test against sites built in any language, for example here is how to test against PHP:

https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/PHP

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is fun and all, but before you make your decision you should consider the impact of Cucumber adoption. You can take a look at what I learned from my experience with Cucumber here [Pitfalls of Cucumber adoption](http://jakubstas.com/pitfalls-of-cucumber-adoption/)